# How connections to SQL Server 2012 are managed in ASP.NET MVC4 applications

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a doubt about how a connection into SQL Server 2012 operates.

If is treated as **per each request data**.

or

If is treated as **per session**, when each user is connected (or the session is alive).

I need to know *how many connections can stay alive depending on*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one connection per request.

If you keep a connection per session, then you will limit the number of sessions to the maximum number of active connections. By using a connection per request you only need as many connections as there are threads handling requests, so the number of concurrent users is virtually unlimited.

Also, the server session ends a long time after the user actually left the site, which would further limit the number of concurrent users.

Even if the database can handle a lot of connections, it's a waste of resources to use a connection per session, and it causes a limitation that is completely unneccesary.